# Angular Material md-select issue with ng-change and ng-required

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

My team is upgrading Angular Material version from v1.0.8 to v1.1.0-rc.5. We have a [`<md-select>`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect) with `ng-required` and `ng-change` function. After the upgrade to the new version of the library, the change function is not executed when the user selects a new value, as you can see in the following code:

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  // if I uncomment this line change myChange function gets invoked the first time
  //$scope.myModel = {};
  $scope.values = [
    {val:1, des: 'One'},
    {val:2, des: 'Two'}
  ];
  $scope.myChange = function(){
    alert('Changed value');
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.css" />

<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" layout-align="center center" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <form name="myForm">
    <md-input-container class="md-block">
      <label>Favorite Number</label>
      <md-select name="myModel" ng-change="myChange()" ng-model="myModel" ng-required="true">
        <md-option ng-value="myVal" ng-repeat="myVal in values">{{myVal.val}}</md-option>
      </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
    myModel.des: {{myModel.des}}
  </form>
</div>
```

This code works fine with Angular Material v1.0.8.

The change function is executed if we remove `ng-required` from `md-select`.

Adding `ng-model-options` with `trackBy` as suggested in the docs doesn't help.

What are we missing?

Comment: It is odd... I created a CodePen with the latest release and it works fine http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/Nrpwzz?editors=1010

Comment: Hi @camden_kid thank you for the comment. I see your codepen and the main difference is that you used `value="{{state}}"`  in the `<md-option>` while I used `ng-value="myVal"`. Moreover your `ng-model="userState"` is a string while my `ng-model="myModel"` is an Object. Changing `ng-value` to `value` triggers change function, but `{{myModel.des}}` in the HTML still does not show anything. I still feel I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
  <form name="myForm">
    <md-input-container class="md-block">
      <label>Favorite Number</label>
      <md-select name="myModel" ng-change="myChange()" ng-model="selected" ng-required="true">
        <md-option ng-value="$index" ng-repeat="myVal in values">{{myVal.val}}</md-option>
      </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
    myModel.des: {{values[selected].des}}
  </form>
```

The `ng-change` is triggered on selection change.

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.values = [
    {val:1, des: 'One'},
    {val:2, des: 'Two'}
  ];
  $scope.myChange = function(){
    alert('Changed value');
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.css" />

<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" layout-align="center center" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <form name="myForm">
    <md-input-container class="md-block">
      <label>Favorite Number</label>
      <md-select name="myModel" ng-change="myChange()" ng-model="selected" ng-required="true">
        <md-option ng-value="$index" ng-repeat="myVal in values">{{myVal.val}}</md-option>
      </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
    myModel.des: {{values[selected].des}}
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, note that the code uses material `<md-select>` and not angular `select`. Are you sure that _an option element can only be bound to string values_ restriction is valid also for this directive? Anyway if I do not get more accurate answer (e.g. explaining why it works without `ng-required` and in the prevoius version), I'll pick this as accepted answer.

Comment: @VincenzoC Looking at the documentation for `md-select` (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect) *it is* possible to use an object as an option element but you need to to add `ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.val'}"` to the `md-select`. Tried that (http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/Nrpwzz?editors=1010) but no luck. It seems that `ng-required` is breaking the `md-select`. Maybe a bug in the latest release. Problem is that they don't appear to be fixing non essential bugs now as they are working on Angular Material  for Angular 2. It may be worth creating an issue though.

Comment: I confirm the it was a problem related to angular material v1.1.0-rc.5. Using new release (1.1.0) the issue seems fixed.